Angular Material: No project index HTML file could be found on ng add @angular/material
I'm trying to use Angular Material on my MFE workspace to show Icons. However, I got the following error when I run the command ng add @angular/material:
No project index HTML file could be found.
I saw two open issues on GitHub that could be helpful:

Cannot download packages with ng add anymore

Angular material install command fails in MFE workspace - Bootstrap
call not found


In the first link, I tried the following solution (in case it works for someone):
ng g @angular-architects/module-federation:boot-async false --project yourProject

ng add your-libraries-of-chioce --project yourProject

ng g @angular-architects/module-federation:boot-async true --project yourProject

But it didn't work for me, it kept showing the same error.
In the second link, I tried the following solution:

Go to my angular.json file
Change my builder from "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser" to "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser"
Delete "extraWebpackConfig": "webpack.config.js", since it give me an error when I tried to run the project (Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(extraWebpackConfig))
Stop the application
run the command ng add @angular/material
Run the application

This helped to install angular material correctly, however still appearing just text instead of the actual icon, this is how I implemented the icon:
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" fontIcon="home">home</mat-icon>

Any idea what else could I do?
PS: It's a good idea to leave @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser instead of ngx-build-plus:browser as a builder on a MFE workspace? So far, I see no errors.
